# Office 365 Document library Sync option not enabled

Tags: document-library, office-365, sync

I had a team site owner contact me wondering why they can't sync to a new file library that they've created.  (See image.)

[image]

So I went and did some exploring.  They added a bunch of content types, and changed the default content type to a visio file and changed the default template to a visio.  I got the document content type to be default and added a word document to be the template.  Didn't make any difference.

They have content approval turned on, I thought that might cause it.  It doesn't.

They have check out turned on to edit, that didn't matter either.

I thought it might be an Asset Library, it isn't.

You can still connect to Windows File Explorer up on the Library ribbon.  When I copy the library and create a template of it, it still retains the same behaviour.

When I create a new document library in that site, it works fine.

I must be missing something, but I'm running out of ideas.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Library settings -> Advanced Settings -> Offline Client Availability. If set to No, you cannot sync it. What is that setting?

Comment: Thanks Eric, but it's set to yes.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Settings --> Search and offline availability --> Allow items from this site to be downloaded to offline clients, set it to 'Yes'. After this settings, it should allow to sync libraries from that site.

Reference post - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Issue-with-Sync-button-missing-in-Modern-Document-Library/td-p/49141